# typescript distribute over union doesnt work in index signature

Tags: typescript

normally we can expect distributive behavior in example like this

```
type a<T>=T extends undefined ? "here":"there"

type b = a<boolean|undefined> // "here"|"there"
```

however this doesnt work in index signature

```
type test<
    L extends { [index: string]: unknown },
> = 
    {
        [K in keyof L]: L[K] extends undefined ?"here":"there"
    }


type e = test<{a:boolean|undefined}> //{a:"there"}, was expecting {a:"here"|"there"}
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer? Then others know it has been answered without reading through the whole question

Comment: done, moved answer to reply section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update I found the answer

```
type a<T>=T extends undefined ? "here":"there"

type b = a<boolean|undefined> // "here"|"there"

type test<
    L extends { [index: string]: unknown },
> = 
    {
        [K in keyof L]: a<L[K]>
    }


type e = test<{a:boolean|undefined}> //{a:"here"|"there"}
```